# Is sufi a sect like shia, sunni?

Tags: sufism

In India most of the muslims converted were through sufi saints. But all these people became either shia or sunni. How? Is sufi a separate sect like shia or sunni?

Answer (score 1):

I got this from a website:
Existing in both Sunni and Shia Islam, Sufism is not a sect, as is sometimes assumed,but a method of approaching or a way of understanding  Islam which strives to take the regular practice of the religion to the "supererogatory level"through simultaneously "fulfilling ... [the obligatory] religious duties" and finding a "way and a means of striking a root through the 'narrow gate' in the depth of the soul out into the domain of the pure arid unimprisonable Spirit which itself opens out on to the Divinity."

Answer (score 0):

Sufi's in Turkey are generally Hanafi. (Based on experience). So they are sunni.